# Qt: How to pull a JSON request from OMDb API

Tags: c++, json, qt

I'm currently working on a school project that involves me using The Open Movie Database API. I feel like I have the request working, but I can't seem to get the information like the Title, Year, etc to appear in the UI or even the console. I tried looking for tutorials about JSON in Qt but I can't find any that are useful. Any help would great!

What I have to pull:

```
void MainWindow::sendRequest(){
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    QObject::connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl(QString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Scarface")));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(req);
    eventLoop.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode the data you can use QJsonDocument, QJsonObject, QJsonArray:

```
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonObject>

void MainWindow::sendRequest()
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Scarface"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(req);
    eventLoop.exec();
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());

    if(document.isObject()){
        QJsonObject valuesO = document.object();

        for(auto key: valuesO.keys()){
            qDebug()<<key<<" : "<<valuesO[key].toString();
        }
        // access by particular key
        //qDebug() << valuesO["Actors"].toString();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
"Actors"  :  "Al Pacino, Steven Bauer, Michelle Pfeiffer, Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio"
"Awards"  :  "Nominated for 3 Golden Globes. Another 4 nominations."
"BoxOffice"  :  "$656,161.00"
"Country"  :  "USA"
"DVD"  :  "30 Sep 2003"
"Director"  :  "Brian De Palma"
"Genre"  :  "Crime, Drama"
"Language"  :  "English, Spanish"
"Metascore"  :  "65"
"Plot"  :  "In Miami in 1980, a determined Cuban immigrant takes over a drug cartel and succumbs to greed."
"Poster"  :  "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjdjNGQ4NDEtNTEwYS00MTgxLTliYzQtYzE2ZDRiZjFhZmNlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_SX300.jpg"
"Production"  :  "Universal Films"
"Rated"  :  "R"
"Ratings"  :  ""
"Released"  :  "09 Dec 1983"
"Response"  :  "True"
"Runtime"  :  "170 min"
"Title"  :  "Scarface"
"Type"  :  "movie"
"Website"  :  "N/A"
"Writer"  :  "Oliver Stone (screenplay)"
"Year"  :  "1983"
"imdbID"  :  "tt0086250"
"imdbRating"  :  "8.3"
"imdbVotes"  :  "572,774"
```

Comment: thank you so much, this was exactly what I was going for. If I wanted to assign "Actors","Title",etc to a Lable in my GUI how would I go about that?

Comment: It would be something similar to: `{your label}.setText(valuesO["Actors"].toString())`

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna try it out, thank you again! Your the best!

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to sort the information by a certain label called title_label but I'm getting two errors inside the        {title_label}.setText(valuesO["Title"].toString()); saying use of undeclared identifier 'title_label' and expected expression

Comment: If you share your code via github or similar I could help you

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I uploaded it on Dropbox since I'm not too good with Github. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6iwxikwrawnl19h/AABd2D-gTOLNgzBRc9epVQg9a?dl=0

Comment: Any luck finding the problem?

Comment: If I found the problem, I am placing the poster  :P

Comment: I already finished, the code is in:
 https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/DankMovieDatabase